# Nodemailer not sending mails after deploying it on docker container

Tags: node.js, express, nodemailer

I have deployed instance of my NodeJS application on docker container. The application is working fine except my Nodemailer module. Nodemailer is not sending emails as required. How can I solve this.

Comment: This is impossible to answer without seeing your code. Have you put any logging in to see what you are getting or where the application is stopping?

Comment: I have this issue too